# How to get the thumbnail from .mov files in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-contentresolver, android-cursor, mediastore

I using the following code to get the thumbnail of `JPG` and `AVI` file , but I can not get the thumbnail from .mov files.

```
String[] projection_image = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, };
            String[] projection_video = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media._ID, };

            File file = new File(viewTag.mFileNode.mName) ;
            String tempfilePath = file.getPath();

            String whereClause_image = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " = '" + tempfilePath + "'";
            String whereClause_video = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " = '" + tempfilePath + "'";

            ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            Cursor image_cursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection_image, whereClause_image, null, null);
            Cursor video_cursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection_video, whereClause_video, null, null);

            try {

                if(image_cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    long thumID = image_cursor.getLong(image_cursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));
                    Bitmap bitmap_image = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getActivity().getContentResolver(), thumID, Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);

                    viewTag.mThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap_image) ;

                }

                if(video_cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    long thumID = video_cursor.getLong(video_cursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));
                    Bitmap bitmap_video = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getActivity().getContentResolver(), thumID, Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
                    viewTag.mThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap_video) ;               
                }

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.i(TAG, "cursor---NullPointerException");

                image_cursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection_image, whereClause_image, null, null);
                video_cursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection_video, whereClause_video, null, null);

            } finally{
                image_cursor.close();
                video_cursor.close();
            }
```

Does somebody know how to get the thumbnail from .mov files by using `MediaStore` in Android ?

Comment: I think .mov file is not supported on android please have a look on supported media type here [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```